# Audio recording in Android (with kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediarecorder

I am working on a trial app to do audio recording in Android (with kotlin).

Here is the problem I currently hit on the way.

In the following code:

```
recordBtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (applicationContext.checkSelfPermission(
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            startRecording()
        }
    }
}
```

The *startRecording()* function does not get excuted because:
*Build.VERSION.SDK_INT = 28* and *Build.VERSION_CODES.S = 31*
And if I remove the test to enforce the excution of *startRecording()*, then as one could expect, the app crashes.

My question is: *what can I do to have a higher Build.VERSION.SDK_INT at least on my own device?*

The research I have done to find the answer on the net do not lead me to a clear answer.

To allow further comment here is the code containing the startRecording() function:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
private fun startRecording() {
    //isRecording = true
    stopBtn.isEnabled = true
    playBtn.isEnabled = false
    recordBtn.isEnabled = false

    val theAudioFile = File(getFilesDir(), "Audio_Record_File")

    mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder(applicationContext).apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
        setOutputFile(theAudioFile)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

        try {
            prepare()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed")
        }

        start()
    }
}
```

The code below to set *mediaRecorder*, does not work either.
Android Studio puts an horizontal line accross MediaRecorder() even if I write:

```
val mediaRecorder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    MediaRecorder(applicationContext)
} else {
    MediaRecorder()
}.apply {
    ......
}
```

And I see this message in the list of problems:

```
Call requires API level 31 (current min is 26): `startRecording`
```

Comment: "the app crashes" you mean because of this @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)?
Maybe you should adapt code to support lower api's?

Comment: @Vadim_Eksler. Well yes, the app crashes inside the function startRecording(), meaning there are good reasons to make the test before running the function. And about adapting the code to support lower api's; that's also an option, but the point is in either case, this is my first time to do audio recording in an Android app and I don't know how to do any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should take a look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder

As you can see constructor `public MediaRecorder (Context context)` added only in API 31.

You can try to use deprecated constructor for API lower than 31, like this:

```
val mediaRecorder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        MediaRecorder(applicationContext)
    } else {
        MediaRecorder()
    }.apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
        setOutputFile(theAudioFile.path)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

        try {
            prepare()
        } catch (e: IOException) {

        }

        start()
    }
```

And remove your `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)` annotation and `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)` check before you call startRecording.

Comment: @Vadim_Eksler. I am also trying to use the code you suggested to set mediaRecorder, but it does not work.
See the update I made to my post.

Comment: `horizontal line accross MediaRecorder()` only means that api deprecated but it should work if you remove RequiresApi annotation.

Comment: Yes, indeed I was finally able to make it work; digging a bit more in the direction provided by your answer.